# matrix multiplication using pthreads_create

Tags: c

I can't figure out where the problem is. I'm guessing it is either the way I'm using `pthread_create` or the way I multiply the index. Can someone help me figure it out? I would like to in the same struct I used.

When I compile it, it returns

```
28 23 18
41 34 27
54 45 36
*** stack smashing detected ./matrix terminated
Aborted (core dumped)
```

The code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define M 3
#define K 2
#define N 3 

int A [M][K] ={{1,4},{2,5},{3,6}};
int B [K][N] ={{8,7,6},{5,4,3}};
int C [M][N];

/* structure for passing data to threads */

struct v
{
    int i; /* row */
    int j; /* column */
};

void *matrix_multiplication( void *ptr );  //the thread

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){


    pthread_t workers[M*N];
    int iret1;
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;
    int a = 1;

    /* We have to create M * N worker threads */
    for (i = 0; i < M ; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++){

            struct v *data = (struct v *) malloc (sizeof(struct v));
            data->i = i;
            data->j = j;

            /* Now create the thread passing it data as a parameter */
            iret1 = pthread_create(&workers[a] , NULL , matrix_multiplication, (void  *) data   );

            a++;
            //free(data);

        }
    }

    //wait for all the threads to be finished   
    for (i = 0; i<10 ; i++){
        pthread_join(workers[i], NULL);
    }

    //printing the matrix
    for (i = 0; i < M ; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
            printf("%d ",C[i][j] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   

    return 0;
}

void *matrix_multiplication( void *ptr ){   

    struct v *data = ptr;
    int sum = 0, z;

    for(z=0; z < K; z++){
        sum += A[data->i][z] * B[z][data->j];
    } 

    C[data->i][data->j] = sum;
    printf("%d\n",sum );
    //threads exit
    pthread_exit(0);

}
```

Comment: Why do you use global variables for this?

Comment: it was a part of the requirement for the seek of the assignment

Comment: `int a=1;` should be `int a=0;` and  `i<10` should be `i<a`. Your array has 9 entries which are indexed 0 thru 8.

Comment: You are leaking memory fast. You can’t release the memory until the threads complete, so you should probably allocate an appropriately sized array of the data structures before the thread creation loop and pass a pointer to a separate element of the array to each thread.  The cast in the thread creation call is not necessary, though it does no harm either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of small errors:

When you create the threads with

```
pthread_create(&workers[a], ...
```

`a` is in the first call already 1, because you've initialized it with 1. That
means that the last `pthread_create` call will access `workers` out of
bounds, you are passing a pointer to an undefined address and this is undefined
behaviour. You should initialize `a` with 0.

The second problem is when you join the threads:

```
for (i = 0; i<10 ; i++){
    pthread_join(workers[i], NULL);
}
```

Because of `a` being initialized with 1, `worker[0]` is not an initialized
thread. The man page does not mention what happens when you pass an
uninitialized thread to `pthread_join`, but my guess is that it is undefined behaviour and most likely the reason
why you have the segfault. I would also write the condition `i < M*N`, because
if you change any of those values, you would be accessing `workers` out of
bounds.

You fail to free the memory for the `struct v` objects, you would have to do it
after the `join`. You are leaking memory there. I don't think that you even need
to use `malloc` here, you can declare an array of dimension `M*N` of `struct v`
objects, just like you did with the `pthread_t` array. When accessing the array,
I'd use `i*N+j` to calculate the correct index for both arrays.

I modified your code with my corrections and my suggestions:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define M 3
#define K 2
#define N 3 

int A [M][K] ={{1,4},{2,5},{3,6}};
int B [K][N] ={{8,7,6},{5,4,3}};
int C [M][N];

/* structure for passing data to threads */

struct v
{
    int i; /* row */
    int j; /* column */
};

void *matrix_multiplication( void *ptr );  //the thread

int main (int argc, char* argv[]){


    pthread_t workers[M*N];
    struct v data[M*N];
    int i = 0;
    int j = 0;

    /* We have to create M * N worker threads */
    for (i = 0; i < M ; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++){

            int idx = i*N+j;
            data[idx].i = i;
            data[idx].j = j;

            /* Now create the thread passing it data as a parameter */
            pthread_create(workers + idx, NULL, matrix_multiplication, data+idx);
        }
    }

    //wait for all the threads to be finished   
    for (i = 0; i<M*N ; i++)
        pthread_join(workers[i], NULL);

    //printing the matrix
    for (i = 0; i < M ; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++){
            printf("%d ",C[i][j] );
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   


    return 0;
}

void *matrix_multiplication( void *ptr ){   

    struct v *data = ptr;
    int sum = 0, z;

    for(z=0; z < K; z++){
        sum += A[data->i][z] * B[z][data->j];
    } 

    C[data->i][data->j] = sum;
    printf("%d\n",sum );
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

As you see, I don't use `malloc`, so I don't have to worry about freeing memory
afterwards. When I run this code, I get:

```
41
45
18
28
27
34
23
54
36
28 23 18 
41 34 27 
54 45 36
```

---

**edit**

> *OP asked in the comment section*
>
> How can I free memory If I used malloc for the struct?!

There are different ways, but the first step is to store the pointer that
`malloc` returns. Right now you are not storing that value.

The first option would be: free the memory in the thread. Let's use your way of
passing values to the threads:

```
struct v *data = malloc(sizeof(struct v));
data->i = i;
data->j = j;

/* Now create the thread passing it data as a parameter */
pthread_create(&workers[a] , NULL , matrix_multiplication, data);
```

Every single thread get's an own `struct v` object and you never use it outside
the thread. That's why you can do this in the thread:

```
void *matrix_multiplication( void *ptr ) {
    ...
    free(ptr);
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

---

Let's say that the parent process needs to get the pointer passed to the thread.
For example because the thread wrote some value there that the main
threads wants to evaluate. Let's say the threads should calculate their
calculation time. Your `struct v` could look like this:

```
struct v {
    int i;
    int j;
    double time;
}
```

The threads would calculate the time and write it on `data->time`. The
thread can pass to the main thread a pointer through `pthread_exit`, in this
case you the thread can pass the same pointer it got from the main thread:

```
#include <time.h>

void *matrix_multiplication( void *ptr ){   

    struct v *data = ptr;
    int sum = 0, z;

    clock_t begin = clock();
    for(z=0; z < K; z++){
        sum += A[data->i][z] * B[z][data->j];
    } 

    C[data->i][data->j] = sum;
    clock_t end = clock();

    data->time = (double)(end - begin) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

    //threads exit
    pthread_exit(ptr);
}
```

Now when you joing the threads, you get the pointer you've pass to the thread,
you can use that pointer and then free it if you don't need it anymore.

```
double agg_time = 0;
for (i = 0; i<M*N ; i++) {
    struct v *data;
    pthread_join(workers[i], (void**) &data);

    printf("i: %d, j: %d ,time: %lf\n", data->i, data->j, data->time);
    agg_time += data->time;
    free(data);
}
printf("aggregated time: %lf\n", agg_time);
```

The output of this would be

```
i: 0, j: 0 ,time: 0.000002
i: 0, j: 1 ,time: 0.000001
i: 0, j: 2 ,time: 0.000002
i: 1, j: 0 ,time: 0.000002
i: 1, j: 1 ,time: 0.000001
i: 1, j: 2 ,time: 0.000001
i: 2, j: 0 ,time: 0.000002
i: 2, j: 1 ,time: 0.000001
i: 2, j: 2 ,time: 0.000014
aggregated time: 0.000026
28 23 18 
41 34 27 
54 45 36
```

If you pass a `malloc`ed pointer to the threads, this is the one I like the most.

---

A third option would be to store the `malloc` data in an array and free it after
the join.

```
int main(void)
{
    ...
    struct v *data[M*N];

    ...

    for (i = 0; i < M ; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            int idx = i*N+j;
            data[idx] = malloc(sizeof *data[idx]);

            data[idx]->i = i;
            data[idx]->j = j;

            pthread_create(workers + idx, NULL, matrix_multiplication, data[idx]);
        }
    }

    // do the join
    for (i = 0; i<M*N ; i++){
        pthread_join(workers[i], NULL);
    }

    // do the free
    for(int i = 0; i < M*N; ++i)
        free(data[i]);
}
```

I don't like this version too much, because it makes the code larger, you need
to check that `malloc` doesn't return `NULL` (I've omitted this test) and have
an error handling strategy for when it fails. That was the nice thing about my very
first code, you don't do `malloc`, you don't have to worry about `free`. However
if you need to pass an allocated block of memory to the thread, I'd do the one
above, where the thread returns the pointer back to the main thread through
`pthread_exit`.

Comment: How can I free memory If I used malloc for the struct?!